# Syntax error in simple trigger

Tags: trigger, sqlite, syntax

I have a `SQLite` table with these fields among others

```
Fld_QuoteNumberRoot     string          
Fld_Revision            integer         
Fld_QuoteNumber         string
```

I need to fill `Fld_QuoteNumber` on every UPDATE and on every INSERT like this:

```
'Q00897' + 4 => 'Q00897/4'
```

Using this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_quote_number AFTER UPDATE on Quote_Base
BEGIN
    UPDATE Quote_Base SET Fld_QuoteNumber = printf('%s/%d', Fld_QuoteNumberRoot, Fld_Revision)
END;
```

I always the error:

> near "END": syntax error

**Questions**
What is wrong with my syntax?

Can I create a trigger which fires on `UPDATE` and on `INSERT` or do I need to define two triggers?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement this is calculated field:

```
create table Quote_Base (
    Fld_QuoteNumberRoot string,          
    Fld_Revision        integer,         
    Fld_QuoteNumber     string   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (Fld_QuoteNumberRoot || '/' || Fld_Revision) STORED
);
insert into Quote_Base (Fld_QuoteNumberRoot, Fld_Revision) values ('Q00897', 4);

select * from Quote_Base;
```

[SQLite online fiddle](https://sqlize.online/s/af)

Answer (score 0):

The `UPDATE Quote_Base ...` needs a semicolon at the end `... Fld_Revision);`

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_quote_number AFTER UPDATE on Quote_Base
BEGIN
    UPDATE Quote_Base SET Fld_QuoteNumber = printf('%s/%d', Fld_QuoteNumberRoot, Fld_Revision);
END
```

Comment: This UPDATE will change all rows in the table.

Comment: @cl is this the correct where clause to restrict it only to the changed row (ID is the primary key): `WHERE id = old.id; `?

Comment: You can use either `OLD.id` or `NEW.id`. What should happen if the `id` is changed?

Comment: It is intended to change `Fld_QuoteNumber` only when `Fld_QuoteNumberRoot` `Fld_Revision` but I don't show it in my example. So to restrict it only to the affected row I should better use NEW.id. Because the id and one of the other may change in one operation and I guess that in "AFTER UPDATE" the id is set already to the new value. Right? (thanks!)

Comment: @CL.  Are "NEW." and "OLD." a single row or a result sets with all affected rows?

Comment: `NEW` and `OLD` are entire rows. In an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, you want to use the new ID. And to prevent recursive trigger calls, use `AFTER UPDATE OF Fld_QuoteNumberRoot, Fld_Revision ON Quote_Base`.